# How can i write exception errors to a multiline text field in a SharePoint list from an event receiver

Tags: development, office-365, error, events, exception

I have a document library on my SharePoint online site, when a user uploads a file in the library a c# itemAdded event is triggered to read the file and store the information in a separate list. This all works perfect. My problem comes in where i need to write any exception errors to a field in the document library. I have a multiline text field in the library already and there are several methods in my code, each method needs to be able to write to the field. How can i do this from the catch method. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case of exceptions is the document get uploaded properly?

Comment: Yes the document is uploading properly, but if an exception is hit, the error is not being stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside the catch block:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    SPListItem item = properties.Listitem;
    item["MultiTextFieldName"] = ex.Message;
    item.Update();
}
```

Comment: I will obviously have to pass the properties to all the methods to use this code?

Comment: You need to pass the ListItem. This is the best way to get hold of that object.

Comment: @Amsal Thank you very much for the help, got it working.